# Probability of no repeated pairs

Tags: probability, combinatorics, simulation

Suppose there is a class with 40 students. The students carry out an initial project in randomly assigned pairs. If the students carry out a second project, what is the probability that none of the randomly assigned pairs of the second project is the same as in the first project? In other words, there can be no repeated pairs in the two projects.

Can anyone provide an answer to this question by using a simulation in R and then by providing a formula?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I've been using the classical definition of probability. If there are 40 students, then there would be 780 possible pairs of students. That is, 40choose2. The second time around, there would be 20 pairs that do not satisfy the event of being new pairs (new in the sense that they are not the same as from the first project). Hence, we need to subtract those 20 pairs from 780. This leaves me with 760/780 = 0.9744  as the probability of no repeated pairs. However, I'm not too sure about this. How did you get to 0.5989?

Answer (score 1):

This is a straightforward application of the [principle of inclusion and exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  There are $$\frac{40!}{2^{20}20!}$$ ways to choose $20$ pairs from $40$ students.  The second time around we must exclude any pair that was chosen the first time.  There are $20$ such pairs, and $$\frac{38!}{2^{19}19!}$$ ways to make $19$ other pairs, which gives  $$\frac{40!}{2^{20}20!}-20\frac{38!}{2^{19}19!}$$  But now any pairing that repeats two pairs has been subtracted out twice, so we must add those back in, and so on.  This gives $$\sum_{j=0}^{20}(-1)^j\binom{20}{j}\frac{(40-2j)!}{2^{20-j}(20-j)!}$$ admissible pairings. Doing the arithmetic, there are $191549525877429961604096$ admissible pairings out of $319830986772877770815625$ possible ones, which gives a probability of $$\frac{191549525877429961604096}{319830986772877770815625}\approx0.5989085917227133$$

If we generalize the problem to $n$ pairings out of $2n$ students, the same reasoning applies, and we find that as $n\to\infty$ the probability that there are no repeated pairs approaches $e^{-1/2}\approx0.6065306597126334$, so that we are already pretty close to the limit when $n=40.$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick simulation in R to go with the answer from @saulspatz:

```
set.seed(1)

pairing <- function() {
  permutation <- sample.int(40)
  lapply(seq(1, 39, 2), function(x) sort(permutation[x:(x + 1)]))
}

repeated_pairing <- function() any(pairing() %in% pairing())

trials <- 1000
results <- replicate(trials, !repeated_pairing())
sum(results) / trials
#> [1] 0.6

plot(1:trials, cumsum(results) / 1:trials)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Probability of person being in same pair second time round is 1/19
So probability of being in different pair is 18/19

So probability of everyone being in different pair is (18/19)^20

Comment: How did you get to 1/19?

Comment: It's not at all clear to me that the events are independent,

Comment: This gives $0.3391392715611757$ whereas the correct answer is $0.5989085917227133$.